# GPS receiver time synchronization and distance measure

Tags: time, gps, synchronization

I've been reading a lot about this system and yet something is misunderstood.
Measuring the distance to satellite no.#2:
The receiver 'sync' it's clock with satellite no.#1 so it knows now is exactly '11:45:551'..
Now let's say satellite no.#2 says 'I sent this pulse in 11:54:550' .
The clocks are synced perfectly between the two satellites.
Assuming the time at the receiver is really accurate, we can now say it's been one millisecond to receive the signal.
So now the receiver should be able to calculate the distance to the satellite.

The problem is with the time sync:
How can we know how much time had been passed from the moment satellite no.#1 sent us the timestamp until the moment we had got it?
Why do we consider the fact that it took time to the message arrive from satellite no.#2 but we do not mention the same issue with satellite no.#1 ?
The 'time' satellite said 'now is 11:45:551' but it took time to receive it, as it took time to receive the pulse from satellite #2 to measure the distance.

I carry this question a lot of time. Hope you'll be able to help me.
Elad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data on the exact orbits of each satellite in the GPS constellation, as well as ionospheric model data, are transmitted as part of the GPS signal. (This data is known as the *GPS almanac*.) This information can be used to calculate the exact position of each satellite from which a signal is being received, which can then be used to determine the amount by which a signal has been delayed on its path to the receiver.